# .net 4.0 GAC can't refer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have installed VS 2010 and builded a project and added the assembly in GAC 4.0.

But How to refer this assembly in a application.

I have created new application and going to add -> reference I couldn't find the assembly which i was installed. But its their if we seen thro' the physical path of the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Add reference' dialog on VS shows you only BCL assemblies, there's a configuration procedure to make it show other assemblies but I don't know it.

What you need to do is have 2 copies of the assembly, one in the GAC and the other somewhere else, lets say c:\libs . When you do 'Add reference' you browse to c:\libs and select it, VS will detect if the assembly is GACed or not.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a tool which is completely free,  that will help you to achieve your goal. [Muse VSReferences](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/36a6eb45-a7b1-47c3-9e85-09f0aef6e879) will allow you to add a Global Assembly Cache reference to the project from Add GAC Reference menu item.